# Failed to build gem native extension when bundle install

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, bundler, bitnami

I am on Windows 7, When I try to `bundle install` I got this error:

```
Installing capybara 2.4.3

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    D:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.0.0-23/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Command 'qmake -spec win32-g++ ' not available
```

Any idea?

Comment: capybara-webkit uses QT, what version of QT do you have installed?

Comment: I am downloading 5.4 now, I still didn't install it ..

Comment: I have QT 5.4 installed, and I have put "D:\Qt2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\bin" in PATH var at windows envs, where qmake.exe is located, but I still get the same error ..